Proof: The Gaussian Kernel as an Inner Product in Infinite-Dimensional Feature Space
Prove that the Gaussian kernel on $ \mathbb{R}^d $ for a positive integer $d $:
\begin{equation}
k(x, x') = \exp(-\gamma \|x - x'\|^2) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for $\gamma > 0 $, can be expressed as the inner product in an infinite-dimensional feature space.
To do so, first prove that if $ k' $ is a kernel on $ X $, then for $ \phi: X \to \mathbb{R} $, it holds that:
\begin{equation}
k''(x, x') = \phi(x)k'(x, x')\phi(x') \tag{2}
\end{equation}
is also a kernel on $ X$. I'm not sure totally how to show it, but I think I on should use the exp power series $exp(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^i}{i!}$. Can anyone help?
